# Filterchange function in viewchild is undefined

Tags: angular, observable, viewchild, kendo-multiselect

I am working on kendo ui angular multiselectdropdown. I have used view child decorator to write business use case for this purpose. If I call asObservable on viewchild filterchange method i am getting error:

> asObservable of undefined.

Comment: Could you provide more code? Also remember ViewChild properties get initilized while the view is rendererd. So you might need to access it in the `ngAfterViewInit` hook.

Comment: @ViewChild('list') list;    this.list.filterChange.asObservable(). In this line I am getting exception asObservable of undefined, and also it is inside ngAfterViewInit